# Vectorizing a summation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, optimization, sum

I am working on a convex optimization problem and I want to calculate the following sum:

[image]

Please note that I have used bold notation for vectors and plain font for numbers. I calculate this expression with this function:

```
function [grad_f_x] = gradient1(b, A, x, n, m)

grad_f_x = zeros(n, 1);

for i = 1:m
   grad_f_x = grad_f_x + 1/(b(i) - A(i, :)*x)*A(i, :).';
end 

end
```

But, I am afraid that while the dimension of the optimization problem n is getting bigger this loop will be very costly and I am trying to find a way to express it using the functions and the operators that Matlab provides like matrix multiplication and `sum(...)`.

**EDIT**

I have tried the following but unfortunately I am not getting the same result:

```
grad_f_x = ((1/(b - A*x))*A).';
```

It may be trivial but note that `.'` operator is the transpose operator and I used period in order to be sure I don't mess with complex number (it might be unnecessary).

Comment: I'm not sure you can write column and line vector multiplications without looping

Comment: 1. Use `\mathbb{}` instead of `\mathfrak{}` for R^n:) 2. I added an answer, but I then noticed your edit. You almost have it right: you need 1./(...)` to get an elementwise division. And it's very good practice to use `.'` properly instead of `'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
grad_f_x=A.'*(1./(b-A*x));
```

In here `A*x` is a matrix multiplication with sizes `(m x n)*(n x 1) -> (m x 1)`, i.e. it's a column vector, with each row telling you `dot(a_i,x)`. You can subtract this from the likewise `m`-length column vector `b`. Using `1./(b-A*x)` we perform an elementwise reciprocal, so this object is still an `m`-length column vector. This is then matrix multiplied with the transpose of `A`, with sizes `(n x m)*(m x 1) -> (n x 1)`, which is a column vector, the same size as `x`.

Comment: I am not sure why but if I use `./` instead of `/` Matlab complains about one of the matrix multiplications (I am not sure which one) i.e. that the matrix dimensions do not agree.

Comment: @koursaros you're right: my original was `(m x 1)*(m x n)`, which doesn't work. I reordered it to have `(n x m)*(m x 1)=(n x 1)`, please check it out:)